# Eliminate duplicates from arrays in Java

Tags: java, arrays

Write a method that returns a new array by eliminating the duplicate values in the array using this header:

```
public static int[] eliminateDuplicates (int[] list)
```

all I have so far is my `main`, but what I wanted to do for the other method was use a for loop to check values at each space in my array and print them if they did not equal any of the other entries.  Working on it as we speak!
 My output is this: The distinct numbers are: [I@4554617c

first of all this is 11 characters and at max I should be printing 10.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class EliminateDuplicates
   {
      public static void main(String [] Args)
     {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Please enter ten whole numbers: ");
        int[] tenNumbers = new int[10];
        for (int i=0; i<10; i++)
        {
           tenNumbers[i] = input.nextInt();
        }             
        System.out.println("The distinct numbers are: " + eliminateDuplicates(tenNumbers));

     }

  public static int[] eliminateDuplicates (int[] list)
     {
        int count = 0; 
        for (int i = 0; i > list.length; i++)
           {
            for (int j = i + 1; j < list.length; j++)
              {

                 if(list[i] == list[j])
                    {
                       list[j] = -1;
                    }                       
              }      
           }


        for (int i = 0; i < list.length; i++)
           {
              if(list[i] != -1)
                 {
                    count++;
                 }

           }
        int[] array2 = new int[count]; 
        int newCount = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < list.length; i++)
           {
              if(list[i] != -1)
                 {
                    array2[newCount] = list[i];
                 }                  
           }      

        return array2;
     }   

   }
```

Comment: "The distinct numbers are: [I@4554617c" They're so distinct they're not even numbers!

Comment: System.out.println("The distinct numbers are: " + eliminateDuplicates(tenNumbers)); prints the reference to an int array. You want to print the contents of the array.

Comment: If you want to output your array via println(), you should use `System.out.println(Arrays.toString(yourArray))` and import `java.util.Arrays`.

Comment: obviously they are not, thats why i posted on here...

Comment: you probably just need `array2[newCount++] = list[i];` (note the ++)

Comment: I suspect this is a homeassignment in an introductory course to computer-science, and you must do it manually? However if that's not the case, you could could iterate the arrau, add all the numbers to a `Set<Integer>` (removes duplicates) and then convert the set back to an array.

Comment: (although this will not work anyway if the array is not sorted, obviously)

Comment: Also for (int i = 0; i > list.length; i++) is incorrect. Change the > sign to < sign.

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.util.ArrayList; 
public class EliminateDuplicates {
//This is called Generics, It'll be a little later in your studies

    public static <E> ArrayList<E> eliminateDuplicates(ArrayList<E> list) {
        ArrayList<E> newList = new ArrayList<>(list.size());
        for (E aList : list) { // for (int i = 0; i <= list.lenght; i++){
            if (!newList.contains(aList)) { 
                newList.add(aList);
            }
        }
        return newList;
    }

public static void main(String[] args) {
    ArrayList<Integer> tenNumbers = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    tenNumbers.add(14);
    tenNumbers.add(24);
    tenNumbers.add(14);
    tenNumbers.add(42);
    tenNumbers.add(25);
    tenNumbers.add(24);
    tenNumbers.add(14);
    tenNumbers.add(42);
    tenNumbers.add(25);
    tenNumbers.add(24);

    ArrayList<Integer> newList = eliminateDuplicates(tenNumbers);

    System.out.print("The distinct numbers are: " + newList);
}
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
import java.util.*;

public class Question {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    int[] arr = {1,2,3,3,4,5,6,1};
    int[] ne = new int[arr.length];
    ArrayList<Integer> already= new ArrayList();
    int i = 0;
    while(i<arr.length){
        if(!already.contains(arr[i]))
            already.add(arr[i]);
        i++;

    }
    System.out.println(already.toString());
    }

}
```

Comment: Please take some time to explain your code sample and how it solves the problem.